# How can I tell Automator to perform a certain action within a software?

Tags: macos, mac, automator

I'm trying to create an Automator application to sync my iMac and MacBook. So far I managed to mount the MacBook and open the sync file in Chronosync.

Now all I need to do is have Automator actually sync.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Run AppleScript action like this:

```
tell application "ChronoSync"
    open POSIX file "/tmp/Untitled.sync"
    Synchronize of document 1
    repeat until syncStatus of document 1 is 0
        delay 1
    end repeat
    save of document 1
    close of document 1
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but AFAIK *Automator* ≠ AppleScript.